# Set TBB as the default browser in Windows XP?

Tags: windows, firefox

I would like to set the Tor browser as my default browser but the setting in options/advanced is not working or will not hold.  How do I fix this?  I'm running Windows XP / Firefox 27.0.1

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm also stuck since Tor isn't listed in the choices for default browser.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple Web browsers on your computer, you can specify which Web browser you want to open when you access the Internet. To set the default Web browser in Windows XP:

From the Start menu, access the Control Panel.  On the Control Panel window, switch to Classic View, if necessary, and choose **Add or Remove Programs**.

[image: control panel]

On the **Add or Remove Programs** window, click on the Set Program Access and Defaults icon.

[image: add_remove]

On the **Set Program Access and Defaults** window, expand the Custom section by clicking on the down arrow.

[image: custom]

In the **Choose a default Web browser:** section, choose the Web browser you would like to be the default and click OK.

Source : [Set Your Default Web Browser in Windows XP - Article 178](http://its.uiowa.edu/support/article/178)

Comment: This did not work. Yes I can get to the set the defaults, but TOR is not listed. Firefox shows itself as the default and it cannot be changed. Further, in the TOR options, it says it is not the default.