# Configure Tor as the predetermined browser in a PC Win Vista

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, windows

Although I stick to the predetermined browser option when installed it doesn't work when a link (http) is opened. What's the matter? 
Further more, Tor doesn't appear among the installed programs list of the Windows control panel! 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Strictly, this is a duplicate of https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1725/tor-default-browser (and perhaps others). But I like this question better. So?

Comment: That's a pity. The question linked for "setting Tor as determined browser" have not any Response. So that, I'll remain still waiting for responses to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The Tor browser does not need installation. All you need to do is unpack the torbrowser-install package. It does not appear among the installed program list of the control panel because it is not installed. It is only unpacked. There is HTTPS Everywhere plug-in activated in Tor browser to provide encrypted version of web pages to users for their protection when an encrypted version of a site is available.

Comment: You beat me by five seconds ;)

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing anything wrong. The Tor browser isn't an installed program. It's just an executable in a folder that you've extracted somewhere. As such, it can't be specified as the default application for HTTP/HTTPS.

In [Tor ticket 12763](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/12763), I see this comment by mcs:

> Replying to lunar:
>   
>   | Do we want Tor Browser to become the default system browser? Correct me if I'm wrong,
>   | but I believe this has privacy implications. Applications would be able to easily open URLs
>   | within the Tor Browser, and link Tor activities with what they know about the system.
>   
>   I agree that applications may be able to take advantage of the fact that the Tor Browser is the default browser. I don't think making TB the system default is something the Tor Project is likely to recommend or do automatically, but some people may want to do so.
>   
>   I am closing this bug.

I haven't found anything specific about setting the Tor browser as default in Windows, but maybe I didn't search enough.

Comment: Dear, I like your answer better.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Anyway I suppoused that. About the other question (predetermined browser) I'll have a look on de attached link.